# Is it possible to receive an airline ticket reservation that can be cancelled?

Tags: tickets, airlines, cancellations

I have not found anything that could give me an idea as how to buy an airline ticket, with a cancellation period let's say one week?

The particular situation is: I want to take my wife to Brazil, but then once we are there I want to take her to Los Angeles.

Basically I would stay a week in Brazil, but the second week would be a surprise.
However, I know she would not allow me to buy the ticket, but if I bought the ticket and had it printed and could show it to her, chances are high that she would say yes, I know her.

however, there is a possibility that she would say no, because of other commitments, etc.

hope this makes sense, basically I want to buy a ticket, and if she says no, I would cancel the ticket.
It could be with any airline that does sao paulo (or any Brazilian city) to L.A. (USA)

Comment: Relevant: https://usattravel.wordpress.com/2015/08/07/6-ways-to-avoid-paying-an-airlines-ticket-change-fee/ , http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/columnist/hobica/2014/02/18/airline-change-fee/5557383/

Comment: So you want to buy a refundable ticket? Isn't there such an option when you buy from some/most airlines?

Comment: I believe that option either costs, or it is limited to 24h, I might be wrong though, hence this research

Comment: have you considered asking a travel agent? most can hold a reservation for you.

Comment: I had not thought about that, I generally buy my tickets online, valid point. Still I am bot buying for me, and I need the ticket in hands, not held for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buy two full-fare tickets.  They are typically fully refundable.  Obviously, check before you purchase.

You typically buy directly from the airline.

Then, whether she says yes or no, get them refunded and buy something sane.  You'll have to pay a small charge, but nothing compared to the fare difference.

Or -- and this is cheaper if you are going to just print the ticket yourself -- forge the tickets completely.  Just take an old ticket and replace the dates and destinations.